# Change origin (0, 0) for layouts

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I want to layout a set of nodes at a specific location, selecting a group of nodes and running a layout so they will orient themselves in that area.

The default layouts seem to find a point between them and layout with that as the origin, but many custom layouts like 2 that I am using like Euler and CISE base everything off of the origin (0, 0) so they move those few nodes to the center, usually under other nodes there and the layout positions them.

Is there anyway to temporarily change the origin position or a hidden option I missed to set the center point for the layout?

Comment: you can run layout for a set of nodes

Comment: Yeah I know that, but I am trying to see if there is a way to edit where the origin point is since these layouts focus everything around the origin (0,0) when I want the nodes to layout around the area they are in.

Answer (score 0):

Some layouts such as [Euler](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-euler) and [Cola](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cola) offers `boundingBox` option to constraint layout bounds. They try to keep the graph elements to be laid out inside those boundaries. I think you may set a specific bounding box with the center point you want for your layout. You can check the readmes of these layouts for more details.